# Cypress: Test fails if request from "cy.route()" is not found

Tags: cypress

I have a question about cypress testing.

I'm doing the following:

`cy.route()` to an url with alias
then `cy.wait(@alias)`

I know that the default action that cypress does it to fail the test if the there wasn't any request made to that url.

My problem is that I have multiple requests and one of them may not reach the request url. But I don't want that to fail my test, just to skip over it. How can I do this?

Basically, I'm asking how do you make your tests NOT to fail when you get this:

```js
CypressError: Timed out retrying: cy.wait() timed out waiting 30000ms for the 221st response to the route: 'productRequest'. No response ever occurred.
```

Comment: Is there any reason to keep a wait for that route()? It isn't best practice to build in some sort of conditional test in Cypress. I would suggest to just remove the `cy.route()` and `cy.wait(@alias)`

Comment: @Mr.J well I have to wait for the page to load to do the rest of the things. Otherwise it will fail finding the elements because the page hasn't loaded yet

Comment: Did some more digging, but it seems there is no solution for this. You could stretch the timeout, but it will still fail since the alias isn't met. And I believe that it is impossible to wait for a request, but if it takes to long, just skip it. I'll keep taps on this issue, curious if someone else does have a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If your usecase is to wait for requests and then continue with more commands, this solution might help you:**

```
describe("route", () => {
    it("hiting route", () => {
        let req1 = false;
        let req2 = false;

        cy.server()
        cy.route({
            methdod: "GET",
            onRequest: () => {
                req1 = true;
            },
            url: "/will/eventually/called"
        });
        cy.route({
            methdod: "GET",
            onRequest: () => {
                req2 = true;
            },
            url: "/will/eventually/called2"
        });

        setTimeout(() => {
            req2 = true
        }, 2000)

        cy.visit("https://biehler-josef.de")

        cy.get("body").should(() => {
            if (req1) {
                expect(req1).to.eq(true);
            }
            if (req2) {
                expect(req2).to.eq(true);
            }
            if (!req1 && !req2) {
                expect(false).to.eq(true)
            }
        });

        cy.get("body").should("exist");
     });
})
```

You define the routes and pass a `onRequest`  function that sets a variable. This can be done with multiple routes. Then you use `should` with callback function. Within that you can check both variables and force to fail only if no request occurred. The `setTimeout`in this example demonstrates a request that takes 2 seconds to finish.

**If you want to check if a request is not hit, it is much easier. But this solution is not usable if you want to execute additional commands after the `cy.wait(@alias)`:**

```
describe("route", () => {
    it("hiting route", (done) => {
        cy.server()
        cy.route("GET", "will/never/be/hit").as("requestalias");

        cy.visit("https://biehler-josef.de")

        cy.on("fail", (error) => {
             if (error.name === "CypressError"
                 && error.message.match(/.*Timed out retrying: cy.wait().*requestalias.*/)) {
                     // calling done forces cypress to turn test to green
                     done()
             }
         });

         cy.wait("@requestalias")
     });
})
```

With `cy.on("fail")` you can listen to the event that is thrown when a test fails. Caling `done()` within this will force the test to be green. But you can not continue with subsequent commands in your test. So the `wait()` must be the last command in your test